# Was Commissioner Gordon ever a woman?

Tags: dc, batman

As it said on the title :
As of 2022, was there ever a Jamie or a Jean Gordon in some variation on the main continuity ?

I'm not talking about another woman being the commissioner (Renée Montoya), or a family member (mother, daughter or wife) of James Gordon taking the interim for a few issues/epilogue.
I'm talking of that women being **The** commissioner (or detective) Gordon.

'It was only a dream' and magical gender bending would be accepted as an answer only if no straight occurrence exists. Same for past and future continuities.
Cross dressing of male James Gordon will be accepted only if he keep the 'stache.

Comment: In Batman Beyond, Barbara Gordon is a Gotham PD Commissioner Gordon. But you don't want daughter of James Gordon to be a commissioner, so it doesn't count :)

Comment: Only at weekends.

Comment: @jo1storm : post your answer anyway, I would probably lower my expectation, and Barbara Gordon will probably fall into 'future continuities' despite being a family member.

Comment: I've voted to close as lacking clarity. You've said 'no family members', then invited someone to answer with a family member

Answer (score 7):

That character hasn't necessarily appeared, but certainly existed.

In [*Superman* vol 1 349](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_349), Mxyzptlk reverses the gender of everyone on Earth just to screw around with Superman (with some exceptions, such as Superwoman and Clara Kent being two separate individuals, and Superman himself not being affected). Although a female version of Gordon isn't explicitly mentioned or seen, you've got Leslie Luthor, Penny White, Jenny Olsen, Batwoman, Wonder Warrior, and so on, so obviously Jamie/Jane/Whatever Gordon would be there as well.

In present DC Continuity, [Earth-11](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-11) is a gender-flipped version.

[image]

Again, although Gordon (her)self isn't seen or mentioned, aside from the gender-flipped superheroes (and supervillains), there was mention of historical figures like President Jackie Kennedy and King Victor of the United Kingdom, celebrities like Lord Gaga, and so on, which makes it safe to assume a female Commissioner Gordon likewise exists.

Comment: I don't think this counts, other than as a 'trick arrow' answer.

Answer (score 4):

In Batman Beyond, both comics and tv show, which is set in the future. Barbara Gordon is the commissioner for Gotham PD.

[image: Barbara Gordon]

She was also a Batgirl in that continuity and the last of bat-family to hang the cape and abandon Batman.

In comics, she first shows up in "The New 52: Futures End" in that role.

Although she does show in main continuity of Batman Beyond comics from the start. She is the focus of issues Undercloud and Batgirl Beyond.

[Batman Beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Beyond_(comics)#Batman_Beyond_and_Batman_Beyond_(vol._2)_DCAU_tie-ins_(1999%E2%80%932001))

Comment: OP was looking for female versions of Jim Gordon, not stories where his daughter is the new commissioner

Comment: And that is not a reason to downvote or vote to close. People change their minds. Was there a female commissioner Gordon is broader than "Was there a commissioner Gordon who is not daughter or wife of male Commissioner Gordon?" and less broad than "Was there a female Gotham PD commissioner?" . I dare say it is clear enough.

Comment: Your answer is perfectly clear, just not an answer *to the question asked*

Comment: Was Commissioner Gordon ever a woman? is the question asked.

Comment: *"I'm not talking about another woman being the commissioner"* sayeth OP

Comment: He wants the commissioner to be called Commissioner Gordon, not Commissioner Montoya.

Comment: As I've said, this is a fine answer to a completely different question ("Has there been a female Commissioner named Gordon?", perhaps), but not to this question.

Comment: For eveyrone in the comment, I did ask jo1storm to post his answer as it was a comment before. while it is different from the main question, it still borderline on the 'future timeline' part of the question